# Error when converting from json2cvs format

Tags: python, json, csv

Someone sent me this code to convert from json to csv format.

Here's the code for json2csv.

```
import sys, json, csv

input = open(sys.argv[1])
json_array = json.load(input)
input.close()

item_data = json_array
if len(item_data) >= 1:
    first_item_id = item_data[0]['item_id']
    columns = item_data[0].keys()

csv_file = open(sys.argv[2], "wb")
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
# there is currently a known bug where column names are partially uppercase, this    will  be fixed soon. the "map(lambda x: x.lower(), columns)" fixes this issue in the mean time
writer.writerow(map(lambda x: x.lower(), columns)) 

# here .items() is a standard python function
for item in item_data:
    row = []
    for column_name in columns:
        if column_name.lower() == 'name_part': # lower required due to above issue
            row.append(" ".join(item[column_name]))
        else:
            row.append(item[column_name])
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Here's my json data.Which I saved as transaction.json

```
{"comment": "Developer test ", "invoice_intern_external_ids": "", "invoice_payments": [{"payment_id": 8, "payment_method": "Refund", "timestamp": "2013-03-05", "invoice_id": 12, "writeoff_reason": "", "payment": 160.0}, {"payment_id": 9, "payment_method": "Cash", "timestamp": "2013-03-05", "invoice_id": 12, "writeoff_reason": "", "payment": 160.0}], "tax": 0.0, "pay_to_external_id": -1, "total": 0.0, "pay_to_contact_id": 13, "client_external_id": 11, "is_draft": false, "invoice_clinician_external_id": 999925, "location": "Therapy A", "invoice_clinician_id": 7, "bill_to_external_id": 11, "timestamp": "2013-03-05", "client_contact_id": 16, "subtotal": 0.0, "invoice_id": 26, "write_off": 0.0, "invoice_items": [{"item_tax": 0.0, "item_name": "InitialVisit_O", "timestamp": "2013-03-05", "item_unit_price": 160.0, "tax": 0.0, "invoice_item_id": 21, "invoice_instance_id": 26, "total": 0.0, "subtotal": 0.0, "item_description": "Initial Assessment/hour", "quantity": 0.0}], "billing_date": "2013-03-05", "invoice_intern_ids": "[]", "bill_to_contact_id": 16, "balance": 0.0, "invoice_instance_id": 12}
{"comment": "", "invoice_intern_external_ids": null, "invoice_payments": [], "tax": 0.0, "pay_to_external_id": -1, "total": 260.0, "pay_to_contact_id": 13, "client_external_id": -1, "is_draft": false, "invoice_clinician_external_id": null, "location": "Sports Medicine", "invoice_clinician_id": 7, "bill_to_external_id": -1, "timestamp": "2013-02-25", "client_contact_id": 15, "subtotal": 260.0, "invoice_id": 23, "write_off": 0.0, "invoice_items": [{"item_tax": 0.0, "item_name": "CompAsses", "timestamp": "2013-02-25", "item_unit_price": 260.0, "tax": 0.0, "invoice_item_id": 36, "invoice_instance_id": 23, "total": 260.0, "subtotal": 260.0, "item_description": "Comp Assess Report", "quantity": 1.0}], "billing_date": "2013-02-22", "invoice_intern_ids": "[]", "bill_to_contact_id": 15, "balance": 260.0, "invoice_instance_id": 10}
```

I tried doing `c:\python.exe c:\json2csv.py c:\transaction.json c:\transaction.txt`
I got the error

```
Extra data line2 column 1 - line 12 column1 (char 1105 - char 11267)
```

If someone can correct the code to fetch all fields then that's great.
I dont even need all fields in csv. I need only `client_external_id`, `invoice_clinician_id`, `invoice_id`, `location`, i`tem_name`, `item_unit_price`, `item_description`, `quantity`, `billing_date`.

This has been pending for a long time.I need to get this completed today.Pls help.

Comment: Your input consists of *multiple* JSON entries, while the code can only handle single JSON data structures. Perhaps you need to read your input file *per line*?

Comment: The code you were sent doesn't match the data structure in your JSON file *at all*. There is no `item_id` key in it, for example, nor a `name_part`. Your JSON structure is also *nested*, which won't translate well to CSV.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems here:

1. Your JSON data is actually multiple JSON datas. That will be hard to fix if you have a lot of data, although Martijns suggestion of reading per line might help, assuming the data really is one JSON mapping per line. Otherwise the data needs to be fixed, like this:

   ```
   [{"comment": "Developer test ", "invoice_intern_external_ids": "" ...},
    {"comment": "", "invoice_intern_external_ids": null, ...}]
   ```

   Note the opening and closing brackets, and the comma after each JSON {} (except the last one).
2. The script you have been given is not particularly generic. It assumes there is an 'item_id' in the first JSON object given, which there is not. That's fixable, though.
3. Your invoice_payments data is a list of dictionaries. This means your data is hierarchical. How do you want to convert to CVS, which is just a flat list of data? It's not obvious. The script you show doesn't deal with that, it's generic and assumes your json data is flat.

A fixed converter:

```
import sys, json, csv

input = open(sys.argv[1])
json_array = []
for data in input.readlines():
     json_array.append(json.loads(data))
input.close()

item_data = json_array
if len(item_data) >= 1:
    columns = item_data[0].keys()

csv_file = open(sys.argv[2], "wb")
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
# there is currently a known bug where column names are partially uppercase, this    will  be fixed soon. the "map(lambda x: x.lower(), columns)" fixes this issue in the mean time
writer.writerow(map(lambda x: x.lower(), columns)) 

# here .items() is a standard python function
for item in item_data:
    row = []
    for column_name in columns:
        if column_name.lower() == 'name_part': # lower required due to above issue
            row.append(" ".join(item[column_name]))
        else:
            row.append(item[column_name])
    writer.writerow(row)
```

yields this result as CSV:

```
comment,invoice_intern_external_ids,invoice_payments,tax,pay_to_external_id,total,pay_to_contact_id,client_external_id,is_draft,invoice_clinician_external_id,location,invoice_instance_id,invoice_clinician_id,bill_to_external_id,timestamp,client_contact_id,subtotal,invoice_id,write_off,invoice_items,invoice_intern_ids,bill_to_contact_id,balance,billing_date
Developer test ,,"[{u'payment_id': 8, u'payment_method': u'Refund', u'invoice_id': 12, u'timestamp': u'2013-03-05', u'writeoff_reason': u'', u'payment': 160.0}, {u'payment_id': 9, u'payment_method': u'Cash', u'invoice_id': 12, u'timestamp': u'2013-03-05', u'writeoff_reason': u'', u'payment': 160.0}]",0.0,-1,0.0,13,11,False,999925,Therapy A,12,7,11,2013-03-05,16,0.0,26,0.0,"[{u'item_tax': 0.0, u'item_name': u'InitialVisit_O', u'timestamp': u'2013-03-05', u'item_unit_price': 160.0, u'tax': 0.0, u'subtotal': 0.0, u'invoice_item_id': 21, u'total': 0.0, u'invoice_instance_id': 26, u'item_description': u'Initial Assessment/hour', u'quantity': 0.0}]",[],16,0.0,2013-03-05
,,[],0.0,-1,260.0,13,-1,False,,Sports Medicine,10,7,-1,2013-02-25,15,260.0,23,0.0,"[{u'item_tax': 0.0, u'item_name': u'CompAsses', u'timestamp': u'2013-02-25', u'item_unit_price': 260.0, u'tax': 0.0, u'subtotal': 260.0, u'invoice_item_id': 36, u'total': 260.0, u'invoice_instance_id': 23, u'item_description': u'Comp Assess Report', u'quantity': 1.0}]",[],15,260.0,2013-02-22
```

Note how your invoice_payments data has been converted to a string:

```
"[{u'payment_id': 8, u'payment_method': u'Refund', u'invoice_id': 12, u'timestamp': u'2013-03-05', u'writeoff_reason': u'', u'payment': 160.0}, {u'payment_id': 9, u'payment_method': u'Cash', u'invoice_id': 12, u'timestamp': u'2013-03-05', u'writeoff_reason': u'', u'payment': 160.0}]",0.0,-1,0.0,13,11,False,999925,Therapy A,12,7,11,2013-03-05,16,0.0,26,0.0,"[{u'item_tax': 0.0, u'item_name': u'InitialVisit_O', u'timestamp': u'2013-03-05', u'item_unit_price': 160.0, u'tax': 0.0, u'subtotal': 0.0, u'invoice_item_id': 21, u'total': 0.0, u'invoice_instance_id': 26, u'item_description': u'Initial Assessment/hour', u'quantity': 0.0}]"
```

Nothing that imports CSV will make any practical sense of that. Your JSON data can not be trivially converted to CSV, you have to decide and specify how the CSV data should look.

Comment: The whole idea is to import the csv data into sql server.Is there a way to store these json objects as fields in a table in sql directly?

Comment: @AnithaYedavalli: Yes, going via CSV is probably not useful in that case. You still need to, as a first step, make a mapping between the JSON data and the SQL data. After that, making an import script is fairly trivial.